# `echo 123 > out.txt` equivalent on windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line

The closest I can come up with is:

```
echo 123 > out.txt
```

However this gives a trailing space and also a trailing newline.

Comment: Echo and cat are different beasts - cat reads a file, echo prints what you give it on the commandline. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @TomNewton Basically, I am creating some scripts in TeamCity to be run during a deployment process.  I need to basically create a text-file from a script that is then later read in by another script during another process

Comment: Then leave out the space before after the ">", and strip the trailing newline when you read the file.

Comment: The original title referred to `cat 123 > out.txt`; I've just edited it to refer to `echo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html

coreutils contains "echo". You can use the "-n" flag to supress the trailing newline

Answer (score 3):

I've used this with success:

```
echo|set /p="123" > test.txt
```

Comment: +1 Neat, although the result still has the trailing space. Tweaked: `>text.txt (echo|set /p="123")`

Comment: Ah, my mistake. The output has a trailing space when the double quotes are omitted (`set /p=123`). It's fine with the double quotes in place (`set /p="123"`).

Comment: It's because you type a space in front of the `>`.

Comment: It worked for me as-is.

Answer (score 2):

In PowerShell:

```
write-output 123 | out-file test.txt
```

There is no trailing space, but there is a newline.

If you want to do this in cmd, the answer you provided in your question is the "correct" way, but there are obvious formatting issues

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this for text-based output:

```
type filename > output.txt
```

Comment: type only works with existing files it seems.  In my case, I want to be able to specify the text inline.

Comment: @CoolUserName: Then your use of "cat" in your question is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Use copy con

```
C:\tmp>copy con mynewfile
This is my new file
I am typing stuff
^Z
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\tmp>type mynewfile
This is my new file
I am typing stuff
```

Press Control-Z to end input

'con' is a keyword signifying console.

copy src dest

copy con mynewfile

src - con - console

dest - mynewfile - destination